# change audiosource on click JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

How can I change a AudioFile on a button click?

First Audiofile should start onLoad and when clicked change to second file. Player shoulden't be Visible.

If possible please answer in JavaSript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var url = "http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/e/e5/Invo_laugh_07.mp3";
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].src = url;
};
```

```html
<audio autoplay src="http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/robocraft.gamepedia.com/c/c6/BattleLoop.mp3"></audio>
<button>button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's so simple :)
Just call a javascript function on a onClick event of a button.

//demo.html

```
<script>
var url = "mymusic.mp3";
function changeURL(){
  document.getElementByIde('audio1').src = url;
}  
</script>


<audio id="audio1" autoplay src="my.mp3"></audio>
<button onclick="changeURL()">Change Audio</button>
```

In the example, the function changeURL() will be call when we click on Change Audio Button.